# Kivy running but no window appear

Tags: kivy

After kivy installation, I ran the code below

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.Button import Button
class Welcome(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = "Welcome to kivy")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wel = Welcome();
    wel.run();
```

No error came up and I got this in my console:

> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in
>   C:\Users\Classic.kivy\logs\kivy_17-05-24_0.txt [INFO   ] [Kivy
>   ] v1.10.0 [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23
>   2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------  Ran 0 tests in 0.000s    OK
>
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in
>   C:\Users\Classic.kivy\logs\kivy_17-05-24_0.txt [INFO   ] [Kivy
>   ] v1.10.0 [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23
>   2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------  Ran 0 tests in 0.000s    OK

My OS is Window 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed line 3 to be `from kivy.uix.button import Button` (not `kivy.uix.Button.`) and it runs fine.

> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

That sounds like you didn't run the program but ran the tests for it instead. What editor are you using? Try running the program from the console.

Comment: I ran initial using eclipse but now it is working using Console. Thank you very much.